# How to remove dots (.) between Numbers in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to remove the dots from the numbers after a string on multiple lines in Notepad++

I have a bunch of lines like this in a file:
`AmountAfterTax="48.85" CurrencyCode="USD" Percentage="50.00"`

I want to delete the dot (`.`) only for the attribute AmountAfterTax like this:
`AmountAfterTax="4885" CurrencyCode="USD" Percentage="50.00"`

I tried this regex:

```
(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)
```

But it also finds the dots for the 'Percentage' attribute, which I want to exclude from the search.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe simply add whole text to the regex: `AmountAfterTax=`

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \bAmountAfterTax="\K(\d+)\.(\d+)
Replace: $1$2
```

### Demo

The above regex first matches `AmountAfterTax="` and then applies the `\K` flag to *reset* the match.  After this point, we match a number with a decimal component, capturing the whole number and fractional parts in separate capture groups.  The replacement is `$1$2`, which effectively removes the decimal point.